# Multiple admins but only one (unremovable) owner of a Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I had a [Facebook Page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Irofoot/160294080660895). I granted admin rights to some chosen fans in order to let them animate the page, with capability of inserting new articles for instance.

However, it happened that one of them removed myself from the "Admin" list.

So my question is: How can I have multiple editors for my Facebook Page with some right restrictions like preventing them from removing the creator of the page?

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

You can now have different roles

[image: Roles in pages]

> Only managers can edit admins for a Page. To add another admin to your
>   Page:
>
> - Open your Page's admin panel
> - Click Edit Page
> - From the left column menu, click Admin Roles
> - Type the names of other people you'd like to add in the open field
> - Click Manager below the name to choose what kind of admin you want to add
> - Click Save Changes

See more information at https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=394501407235259
It still appears as though any admin can remove you from the page.